# no exact matches in call to initializer.(I do not know how to fix it)

Tags: swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var countries = ["dubai","Dutch","Finland","france","france","Fuji","India","Intaly","Japan","Korean","nepal","pakistan","philippe","Rusia","swiss","Tailand"].shuffled()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0...2) { number in Image(self.countries[number])(error here:no exact matches in call to initializer.)
                    .border(Color.black,width:1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more info

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes you have image assets named the same as the `String Array` `countries`. The problem is you are attempting to initialize a ForEach like you would a `for...in`. While they are both loops, they are not the same.

I have given example code below, but better practice would be to create a data model struct called "Country" that is `Identifiable` where one of the parameters is the name of the image. That way you can use one `ForEach` and show various data on the country, like name, population, geography, etc. `var countries` would then be typed like this: `var countries: [Country]` and your `ForEach` would be simplified.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var countries = ["dubai","Dutch","Finland","france","france","Fuji","India","Intaly","Japan","Korean","nepal","pakistan","philippe","Rusia","swiss","Tailand"].shuffled()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // The ForEach will loop through each element and assign it to
            // country for use in the closure where Image() is.
            ForEach(countries, id: \.self) { country in
                Image(country)
                    .border(Color.black,width:1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```